# Could we use SGX's enclave to execute a flow in Corda?

Tags: corda

I've been studying Corda for a while but I'm a newcomer with SGX.

As far as I've researched, SGX's enclave could help us do the transaction resolution in many approaches by running the modified JVM inside an enclave. Therefore, the code that running inside an enclave should be Contract code for verifying a transaction. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I was wondering is it possible to change the code from Contract code to Flow code to be executed in an enclave? I do believe that flow session would be a huge constrain for implementation but is it possible to use the same channel/method as remote attestation to do the communication instead of the original flow session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a lot harder to run flow code inside an enclave than contract verification code because flow code is a lot less constrained. It can do anything the host Java platform can do. SGX on the other hand is an unusual environment in which nothing works by default (there's no operating system access), so every request has to be tunnelled through a custom ECALL/OCALL interface. And that's not trivial because the operating system is untrusted, so, you can't just build a simple syscall relay (well, people have tried). Everything has to be encrypted, authenticated, and so on.

The goal of our SGX work is to allow people to run more and more logic in the enclave, as well as developing "enclavelet" apps that aren't Corda specific and can do other things. So we'll get there, but it might not look like running flows entirely inside an enclave.